# why interrupt routine not stopping?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, x86-16

i am trying to create custom interrupt...for int 40h,int 42h,int 45h.i have created the vector design but after the IRET instruction call it's showing errors that instruction has not been defined yet...how to fix this...

i am trying to add,subtraction,division and multiplication using the interrupt i have tried so far:

```
code segment
    assume cs:code,ds:code
    org 1000h

    mov ax,0000h
    mov ds,ax  





    mov bx,40h*4
    mov ax,offset add
    mov word ptr [bx],ax
    mov dx,0
    mov word ptr[bx+2],dx 




    mov bx,42*4
    mov ax,offset sub
    mov word ptr [bx],ax
    mov dx,0
    mov word ptr[bx+2],dx 


     mov bx,45*4
    mov ax,offset div
    mov word ptr [bx],ax
    mov dx,0
    mov word ptr[bx+2],dx


     mov bx,48*4
    mov ax,offset mul
    mov word ptr [bx],ax
    mov dx,0
    mov word ptr[bx+2],dx



    mov cx, 01h;

    cmp cx, 01h
    jz 40hh 

    cmp cx, 02h
    jz 42hhh 

    cmp cx, 03h
    jz 45hhh 

    cmp cx, 04h
    jz 48hhh 




    40hh:
    int 40h 



    42hhh:
    int 42h



    45hhh:
    int 45h 


    48hhh:
    int 48h 





    add:
    mov dl,40h
    mov dh,30h
    add dh,dl
    iret


    sub:
    mov dl,40h
    mov dh,30h
    sub dl,dh
    iret

    mul:     
    mov al,4h
    mov bh,3h
    mul bh
    iret

    div: 
    mov ax,40h
    mov cx,05h
    div cx
    iret



        e:    ret

    int 21h
```

Comment: I don't have the energy to try to fix this, but you need to do more than you are doing in the interrupts themselves.  Have a look at a good basic reference on DOS based assembly and interrupt hooking

Comment: Also, you fall straight through your supposed interrupt handlers as your code ends, which is a horrible idea.

Comment: comment your code.  Also, use a debugger to single-step through it.  This isn't a [mcve]; it could be way shorter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the [PSP](http://devel.archefire.org/en/projects/x86/OS/LowEST/_/dospsp.html) is 256 (100h) bytes long, not 4KiB (1000h).
So replace `ORG 1000h` with `ORG 100h`.

Second of all, you cannot make assumption about the segment your program will be loaded into, once in memory.
Actually you can make one: It **won't** surely be loaded at segment 0, because that segment has an already crowded beginning<sup>1</sup>.
Yet, you do this

```
mov dx,0
mov word ptr[bx+2],dx
```

Which set the segment part of the far pointer in the IVT entry to zero, thus assuming that `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `div` will be into segment zero.
Replace `mov dx,0` with `mov dx, cs`.

Finally your code is running wild at the end, passing through all the calls to the interrupts and the first ISR itself!
You can use [Int 21/AH=4Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm) to terminate a program.
Before exiting, you **should** restore the original ISRs though.

**Note**, there are some code smells.

You set up `DS` to point to segment zero in order to write the IVT entries, however, unless you'll never do any non segment-overrided memory access, leaving it to point to another segment is usually a bad idea.

The "switch" is missing the "breaks". Each branch of your program flow merge into the following one (ie. a jump to `40hhh` will also execute code from `42hh`).

The `div` ISR don't set up `dx` before the `div`.

The ISRs themselves are pretty arbitrary and they clobber the registers, unless this is just a prototype, they will be a nightmare to use in any real program.

---

<sup>1</sup> As you know, since you are writing the IVT that sits at the beginning of segment 0.